# Why I can't match a string using SQL and Access?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm using C# to retrive data from MS Access. When I'm trying to set up a query that "collects" numbers, everything workd good, but when i'm dealing with strings everything goes crazy.

Basically, I have a data base that simulates the periodic table. I have columns like state of matter, density, atomic number etc.

Let's say that I want to get all the elements with an atomic number greater than 20. My query will be as follow :

```
"Select * From Periodic Where (AtomicNumber > 20)"
```

This gives me exactly what I want. But le'ts say I want all elements with an atomic number greater than 20 and are currently in a gas state. So I tried something like :

```
"Select * From Periodic Where (AtomicNumber > 20 AND StateOfMatter = Gas)"
```

Failed. It throws an error stating :

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112264/c-sharp-oledb-exception-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-whi). I've tried everything, including all these queries :

```
 "Select * From Periodic Where (AtomicNumber > 20 AND StateOfMatter = `Gas`)"
 "Select * From Periodic Where (AtomicNumber > 20 AND StateOfMatter LIKE `Gas`)"
 "Select * From Periodic Where (AtomicNumber > 20 AND StateOfMatter = `%Gas%`)"
```

Everything gives me the above error. I'm trying to solve this for two days now, but with no success.

Here is my C# code that creates the connection :

```
private void ConnectToDataBase(string Query)
    {
        OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter;
        DataTable LocalDataTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            DBConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\PeriodicTable.accdb;
                                              Persist Security Info=False";
            DBConnection.Open();
            DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, DBConnection);
            // The error occurs here.
            DataAdapter.Fill(LocalDataTable);

            if (Elements.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            DBConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it? Why matching strings is so much harder than numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `StateOfMatter` is a character typed, you need to use it's value with single quotes like;

```
StateOfMatter = 'Gas'
```

[` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm) ([grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)) is not equal to [' character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) ([apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe)).

And since `OleDbCommand` doesn't *care* about parameter names, it thinks your `Gas` is a parameter and that's why it says;

> No value given for **one** or **more** required parameters.

Because it *knows* if this is not a parameter, it should be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: OMG!!!... Lol, I feel so stupid right now. Pffff, I switched ` and '. Well, thanks xD