# Error on Search Button

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I searched on some codes on how to do a Search Button in VB.net. But somehow, it won't work because of an error. And simply because, I cannot understand its algorithm and function. Newbie here. Anyway, here is the code for the search button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myConnection.Open()
    crd.Clear()
    fn.Clear()
    ln.Clear()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM tblReg WHERE (Code = '" & src.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        crd.Text = dr("crd").ToString
        fn.Text = dr("fName").ToString
        ln.Text = dr("lName").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

And the error was on:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

And VB said:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112264/c-sharp-oledb-exception-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-whi

Comment: @DanielShillcock The OP already has the single quotes around the value.

Comment: @GSerg And if `src.Text` contains an apostrophe? ;-) OP should be using parameterised queries.

Comment: Even worse than an apostrophe was `'; Drop Table tblReg;`

Comment: @DanielShillcock Then it would be an invalid SQL expression error, unless `src.Text` [also contains `--`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683), but then there would be no error at all. They should be using [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/11683), it's just that particular question is not the relevant one.

Comment: @GSerg Perhaps, but if you read the upvoted comment in that question, it's well worthy of mention.

Comment: If `src.Text` is numeric, you must remove the apostrophe here `Code = '" & src.Text & "'` then will be `Code = " & src.Text & "`

Comment: So uh, what do I do? I changed it, but then, I still got errors.

Answer (score 0):

One should not follow online tutorials that teach very bad code. [That code](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/ReadFromAccess.htm) is very bad because it contains [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683) and leaves database objects opened.

You should rewrite your code as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myConnection.Open()
    crd.Clear()
    fn.Clear()
    ln.Clear()

    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblReg WHERE Code = ?", myConnection)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        With cmd.Parameters.Add(Nothing, OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
            .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            .Value = src.Text
        End With

        Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()
                crd.Text = dr("crd").ToString
                fn.Text = dr("fName").ToString
                ln.Text = dr("lName").ToString
            End While
        End Using
    End Using

    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

You have to use question marks in place of parameters because you are using `OleDbCommand` that [does not support named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2407685/11683).

Change `OleDbType.VarChar` to your actual column type.

Comment: I'll try that one out. Thank you so much. :>

Comment: I still get the errors on `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()` plus when I replaced the `OleDbType.Varchar` , it won't accept it.

Comment: Are you sure the error is at `cmd.ExecuteReader`, and what did you replace it with?

Answer (score -1):

Is this the link where you get the code?

http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/ReadFromAccess.htm

Kindly do not get the code read each data on the output shows and also check this part of the code.

```
 crd.Text = dr("crd").ToString
        fn.Text = dr("fName").ToString
        ln.Text = dr("lName").ToString
```

are you sure `crd,fname,lname` are the name of your fields in your table? pls check it and also what is the field type of `code?` is it a text or INT that is Auto Increment? or just an INT? no matter what it is change your code.

from

`str = "SELECT * FROM tblReg WHERE (Code = '" & src.Text & "')"`

to

`str = "SELECT * FROM tblReg WHERE Code =" & src.Text`

Updated

I suggest better read or follow the whole instruction based on link where you get your code. I suggest do the same as what the link said create the same and when the program runs with no error then incorporate it with your program beacuse I tried it using VB.NET and Access and it worked Im sure you dont read it. Do this and Im sure you will not just get the code you need you will also learn.

Comment: Yes yes. They are the name of my field. I triple checked them. What `code` ? Hahaha. :> Thank you. :D

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM tblReg WHERE Code =" & src.Text` replace your code with this

Comment: Oh. Okay. I have another question, the tblReg is the name of my table. Do I replace it or no? Because I need to get the information from the field of crd.

Comment: What is the name of your table that you will get those data?

Comment: theres nothing funny i think? I am also same as  you Pinoy, so you mean that your tapping a card and after tapping tapping the card the number shows in the textbox? Right

Comment: Yes. Then, click search then kaboom. The other data would be in the textbox. Just as where I did get my code. :D

Comment: what database did you use?

Comment: I used access. :)

Comment: I tried to do the same, and it still won't work. I cry. :<